# Catching an error of a coroutine launch call

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

in the following code:

```
private fun executeCognitoRequest(result: MethodChannel.Result, block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Any?) {
  try {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
      val requestResult = block()
      withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        result.success(requestResult)
      }
    }
  } catch (exception: Exception) {
    val cognitoErrorType = CognitoErrorType.getByException(exception)
    result.error(cognitoErrorType.code, null, null)
  }
}
```

if the call to `block` throws, will it be caught?

Answer (score 1):

It will be caught, but the problem with your code is that you violate the principles of structured concurrency and launch a coroutine in the `GlobalScope`. So if you test your code from a main function like this:

```
fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        executeCognitoRequest(MethodChannel.Result()) {
            funThatThrows()
        }
    }
}
```

the whole program will end before the coroutine has completed execution.

This is how you should write your function:

```
private fun CoroutineScope.executeCognitoRequest(
        result: MethodChannel.Result,
        block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Any?
) {
    try {
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val requestResult = block()
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                result.success(requestResult)
            }
        }
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        val cognitoErrorType = CognitoErrorType.getByException(exception)
        result.error(cognitoErrorType.code, null, null)
    }
}
```

Now your function is an extension on `CoroutineScope` and `launch` is automatically called with that receiver. Also, for blocking IO calls you shouldn't use the `Default` but the `IO` dispatcher.

However, I find your higher-level design weird, you start from blocking code and turn it into async, callback-oriented code. Coroutines are there to help you get rid of callbacks.